# EJB and Hibernate: Table dosen't exist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ejb-3.0

I am working on this application where I need to get a result list from MySql database, but everytime I run it on the server(wildfly 9) I am getting an error that the table dosen't exist.Here is the code in my EJB :

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MessageService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="primary")
    EntityManager em;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public List<Message> customers = new ArrayList<Message>();

    public List<Message> findAll() {
        customers= em.createQuery("select c from Message c").getResultList();
        //customers = query.getResultList();
        System.out.println(customers.size());
        return customers;
   }
```

and this is My Entity :

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Message.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM Message m")
public class Message implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int idMessage;

    private String discriminateur;

    private int numFenetre;

    private String texte;
```

and this is my persistence.xml :

```
  <persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed 
         data source, this example data source is just for development and testing! -->
      <!-- The datasource is deployed as <EAR>/META-INF/MavenEar-ds.xml, you
         can find it in the source at ear/src/main/application/META-INF/MavenEar-ds.xml -->
      <jta-data-source>java:/mysql</jta-data-source>
      <class>com.model.entities.Message</class>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <!--  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />-->
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

PS: I am did set a datasource on wildly that links to the database.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 126 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'christina.message' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 142 more
```

Comment: can you show the error? are you sure the table doesn't exist? are you sure it is connecting to the right database?

Comment: I am sure the table exists and this is the url in my datasource ' 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/christina' it clearly points to the right database. I will add the stack trace

Comment: @Tiny thanks already solved the problem.Check my comments under the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
```

I think it might be looking for christina.christina.message. otherwise the error would just say table "message" not found.  how is your entity annotated?  Are you using a custom naming strategy or dialect?

Comment: I added the property but still the same error. My entity is annoted with the regular `@Entity` above it , that's it

Comment: I don't know. I still suspect it is trying to access the wrong schema or something.  I usually turn on the mysql query log so I can see all queries hitting it.  that should tell you exactly if it is indeed hitting the right schema or not.

Comment: Oh my bad, turns out that the `create-drop` dropped the table before I comment it so I was foolishly really looking for a Table that dosen't exist. I fixed it now.